# Need output as to if somewhere within the first array consists second array

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

```
public boolean contains(int[] a,int[] b) {
int w=0;
for(int i=0;i<a.length && w<b.length;i++) {
    if(a[i]==b[w])
    w++;
    else w=0;
}
System.out.println(w);
if(w==b.length) return true;
else return false;
```

}

---

This code is failing for the scenario-contains({1, 2, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3})-for obvious reasons. However, i can't put the right code in that amends the right output. Please help me out.

Comment: Hint: you need two for loops.

Comment: I'm a little unsure about what you are trying to do; are you trying to make it so that you see if all elements in 1 array are present in another array?

Comment: You need to describe what you are trying to do, what you have tried to accomplish it, and possible solutions you researched and attempted. Doing so will help make your question more concrete and you are more likely to get better help.

Comment: Your task is a classic alogrihtm of finding substring in a string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765579/fast-algorithm-for-searching-for-substrings-in-a-string

Comment: @JoshM yes, that's exactly: see if string b is substring of string a.

Comment: @DustinE.Thanks Dustin. I'll try to do as you told from now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        public static boolean contains(int[] a,int[] b) {
        String s1=  Arrays.toString(a).replaceAll("\\[|\\]","");
        String s2=  Arrays.toString(b).replaceAll("\\[|\\]","");

        if(s1.contains(s2)){
          return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        }
```

Live [Demo](http://ideone.com/qHdnMR)

Problem in your code

```
      for(int i=0;i<a.length && w<b.length;i++) {//a={1, 2, 1, 2, 3},b= {1, 2, 3}
        if(a[i]==b[w])// first two element are same in both arrays
            w++;// then w=2, but a[2] !=b[2]. 
        else w=0;// So w=0, but in next round it will check 
          //equality as a[3]==b[0] that's false.
       }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `return Arrays.asList(a).contains(Arrays.asList(b))`?

Comment: @JoshM no that is not applicable here.

Comment: @JoshM: I tried and it is failing for anonymous reasons. Could you explain why it is failing here?

Comment: @Ruchira: Why is that solution given by failing. You earlier exuded confidence that it would not work. Could you substantiate as to why?

Comment: @BharathBallamudi check my answer now. You can see why your code not working