# Compare values between a .txt file and editText

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a blacklist for my app, so any word that exists in the blacklist.txt file is inputted by user via editText will be flagged out. The code I have below is not doing anything and I don't know why.

```
private  String comparevalue()  {
    BufferedReader buffered = null;

        String val = editbox.getText().toString();
        InputStream inputStream =getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.blacklist);
        buffered = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    try {
        String line = buffered.readLine();
        while (line != null) {

            line = buffered.readLine();

        }if (val.equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    **}
    return buffered.toString();
}**
```

Comment: You're doing the if outside the while. So you're just comparing val with null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put the if outside the while. So you're just comparing val with null.

Put it inside the while, and before `buffered.readLine()`, so you're not ignoring the first line. Something like this:

```
line = buffered.readLine();
while (line != null) 
{
    if (val.equalsIgnoreCase(line)) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    line = buffered.readLine();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this

```
while (line != null) {

        line = buffered.readLine();
        if (val.equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: in a case I have a statement not just a word in my editText how can I loop through all the words to detect words that exists within the backlist.  if (val.equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
                for (int i=0;i>val.length();i++){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

Comment: if you are going to match more than just one word then it is good go with a string matching algorithm like rabin carp https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm or look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/1765616/4363046